# Let $f:A\to B$ s.t. $f$ bijective, $A$ compact and $B$ hausdorff. Why $f^{-1}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f:A\longrightarrow B$ a bijective continuous function such that $A$ is compact and $B$ is Hausdorff. Why does it implies that $f^{-1}$ is continuous ? I tried to show that $f$ is an open function, but I didn't sucess. Any idea ?

Comment: See for instance [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism).

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @Bernard Good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate Q................

Answer (score 3):

Show that $f$ is closed instead. If $X \subseteq A$ is closed, then it is compact (as a closed subset of a compact space). Then $f(X)$ is compact as a continuous image of a compact set. Show that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space must be closed and conclude that $f(X)$ is closed.